# Using wc_get_products function in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Bit puzzeled here.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'foobar' );

function foobar(){
    $products = wc_get_products(array());
    var_dump($products);
}
```

This returns empty array. It doesn't seem to make difference what parameters I add to args. All I get is empty result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated**

First `plugin_loaded` hook does not seems to be the right hook for this (but may be I am wrong)…

Now you need To add some minimal arguments to get your products:

```
$products = wc_get_products(array(
    'limit'  => -1, // All products
    'status' => 'publish', // Only published products
) );
```

To see the output in top of cart page (for example) to be sure you get something try just for testing purpose:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'custom_raw_output' );
function custom_raw_output(){
    $products = wc_get_products(array(
        'limit'  => -1,
        'status' => 'publish',
    ) );
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($products); echo '</pre>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works...

[The documentation for wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#parameters)

Comment: Yep. Totally right. It was the action that made the issue. Didn't even consider it.

Comment: what action did you correct your work with in the end to make it work? @sarte

Comment: @kadddeee It totally depends on what you are trying to achieve. On my particular issue "plugins_loaded" action wasn't called can't recall why. Check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112593/why-is-plugins-loaded-not-called-fired This might help you

Comment: I think the status should be "publish" and not published

Comment: @SvetoslavMarinov Oups! Yes you are completely right